# Comparing each element of two Arrays - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, loops

### Objective

I want to compare each element of two arrays, when an element does not match in both of them, it gets pushed to another array.

**Both array are of indefinite size.**

### Code So Far

```
Example:
//namelist will always have the values present, userlist will check if it has the elements in namelist, otherwise send to another array.

namelist = ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5']

userlist = ['user4','user1','user3']  //'user2' and 'user5' are not present


//Does not work

let arr1 = [];

let arr2 = [];

for(let i = 0; i < namelist.length && userlist.length; i++){

    if(namelist[i] == userlist[i]){

        arr1  = userlist[i]
    } else {

        arr2  = userlist[i]
    }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: How do you want to handle dupes like `["a", "b", "a"]` and `["a", "a", "a"]`? What's the expected output for the given arrays?

Comment: Do you expect an array which contains `namelist` items not found in `userlist` array?

Comment: @ambainBeing, Yes exactly.

Comment: @ggorlen, there will be no dupes, because I am extracting from a database, so there wouldn't be any dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate on `namelist` and check item from this array exists in `userlist` using [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If `false` add to `result` array.

```js
    const namelist = ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5'];
    const userlist = ['user4','user1','user3'];

    let result = [];
    namelist.forEach(name => {
    if(!userlist.includes(name)){
    result.push(name);
    }
    });
    
    console.info('result::', result);
```